# Ruby On Rails searching database for word

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I am trying to search a database in MySQL where the term I am searching may be one word in the column string. For example if the cell was "this is a very lovely day" then I would like to be able to call that object by searching for the word 'lovely'

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a LIKE query. (i.e. `foo LIKE %bar%`) The % represents a wildcard operator. bar% would be "starts with bar" and %bar% would be "contains bar." Note that *contains* searches cannot use column indexes and will be slow.

Suppose you had a `Day` class with the attribute `description`. In that case, you would do

```
Day.where("description LIKE '%lovely%')
```

Comment: `Day.where("description LIKE ?', '%lovely%')`
It is a bad practice to provide arguments with the query string

Answer (score 0):

by using Arel

```
days = Day.arel_table
Day.where(days[:description].matches("%lovely%"))
```